# How to check if `compute_gradients` operation has been executed in tensorflow graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

**Here's my use-case**
I am trying to implement the [Model Agnostic Meta Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03400) algorithm. At some phase of the training process I need to calculate the gradients of some variables without actually updating the variables and at a later step I would like to do certain things ONLY if the compute gradient operations are complete.

A simple way to do this is to use `tf.control_dependencies()`

```
# In this step I would like to COMPUTE gradients
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
# let's assume that I already have loss and var_list
gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss, var_list)

# In this step I would like to do some things ONLY if the gradients are computed
with tf.control_dependencies([gradients]):
    # do some stuff
```

**Problem**
Unfortunately the above snippet throws an error since `tf.control_dependencies` expects `gradients` to be a `tf.Operation` or `tf.Tensor` but [`compute_gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.6/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdamOptimizer#compute_gradients) returns a `list`.

Error message:
`TypeError: Can not convert a list into a Tensor or Operation.`

**What I would like?**
I would like one of two things:

- A way for me to get either a `tf.Operation` or a `tf.Tensor` from the `optimizer.compute_gradients` function that I can use in`tf.control_dependencies`.
- Or any other reliable way for me to check if `optimizer.compute_gradients` is actually computed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `gradients` is the list of (gradient, variable) pairs you'd like to make sure being calculated, you can covert it to a list of tensors/variables and use it as the `control_inputs`:

```
with tf.control_dependencies([t for tup in gradients for t in tup]):
```

Comment: That's nice and simple! I'll test it out. I had thought about something similar but I didn't go through with it because in the docs it says `Variable is always present, but gradient can be None.` Do you know under what circumstances it can be None?

Comment: @nitred Please checkout [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/783)

Comment: It worked! But I had to change my entire architecture to be a lot more simple. I checked out the issue and it seems like I most likely won't face these issues provided I carefully construct the graph:
1. There is no connection from input to output.
2. There is a connection, but it's through a discrete variable with meaningless gradients.
3. There is a connection, but it's through an op that doesn't have an implemented gradient.

Comment: @nitred Thanks for the feedback.